# SSMS suddenly starts generating DEFAULT constraints inlined into the CREATE TABLE statements instead of ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've been using SSMS to generate scripts of the whole database and storing them in the source control.

[image: ssms]

[image: options]

It's been working fine for many years, but few days ago I noticed that SSMS started generating `DEFAULT` constraints as a clause inlined into the `CREATE TABLE` statement instead of adding a separate `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Here is an example of one table. 
This is how the script looked like before:

```
USE [my db name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsignmentGroups](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ConsignmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ConsignmentGroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsignmentGroups] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ConsignmentGroups_Notes]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Notes]
GO
```

Here `DEFAULT` constraint is scripted as a separate `ALTER TABLE` statement.

This is how it looks like now:

```
USE [my db name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsignmentGroups](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ConsignmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ConsignmentGroups_Notes]  DEFAULT (''),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ConsignmentGroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here `DEFAULT` constraint is inlined into the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

It didn't happen to all tables with `DEFAULT` constraints. There are about 60 tables with `DEFAULT` constraints and at least one of them is still scripted as `ALTER TABLE` statement. I don't think anyone touched the table in the example above (`ConsignmentGroups`), there were no changes to the table structure. The only change is the style of `DEFAULT` constraint.

The problem is that this kind of change in the T-SQL script is picked up by the source control as a change. I'd like to know how to control it to avoid it in the future.

I assume that I accidentally changed some setting in SSMS without realising what it does. Does anyone know where this setting could be?

I use SQL Server 2008 Standard

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64) 
    Sep  3 2014 04:11:34 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
```

SSMS 2012

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio     11.0.6020.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)    6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                            3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                9.11.9600.18376
Microsoft .NET Framework                   4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                           6.1.7601
```

and [SSMS Boost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) build 2.19.5952.29737

I don't remember updating any of these components or changing any settings for a while, but apparently something has changed.

---

I tried to generate these scripts using SSMS 2014 (12.0.4459.0) without SSMSBoost installed on a virtual machine that I don't usually use.

To my surprise the result was the same. The scripts generated by different versions of SSMS running from different computers are identical. This means that it is not a setting in SSMS, there must be something in the database itself.

Also, the fact that one table out of ~60 is scripted differently suggests that this setting is not database-wide, but works on a table level.

Comment: Was this ever answered?
As stated, the Connect item didn't help much, and now it's not there anymore, it is even less helpful.

Comment: Sorry, @David, I didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

This 'might' be the problem, although, there does not appear to be a 'solution'.  I was able to reproduce your issue. See this connect item regarding this problem:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/895113

> The SQL SMO generates for a table with defaults depends on the rowcount of the table. This makes it impossible to programmatically compare the schema.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this Connect item, but it doesn't help much unfortunately. I'm trying to figure out what I did before this sudden change in SSMS scripting. In my case SSMS was generating `DEFAULT` constraints using `ALTER TABLE` for all tables regardless of how many rows they have. But now it started to behave as described in this Connect item - it generates the script differently for empty and non-empty tables.

Comment: having a single row instead of an empty table solved it for me. i was trying to do the opposite and get everything into the create table statement. thanks